# Trying to deploy Django in windows machine

Tags: python, django, windows, apache

Hellos guys I’m trying to deploy django in a Windows machine, I already change python versions and wsgi_mod many times and it seem to be correct the problem is when I try to add the application in settinf.py, if I only create the Project and I run 127.0.0.1 it works fine it show me the django welcome message but once I juts create the app and I add in the setting.py it show me 500 Internal Server Error error, could you guys help me with this issue?

This is my apache error log.

```
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:07.620085 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6032:tid 564] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:07.620085 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6032:tid 564] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 12:12:07
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:07.620085 2018] [core:notice] [pid 6032:tid 564] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:07.635705 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6032:tid 564] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4604
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:08.541998 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4604:tid 564] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.172721 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432] mod_wsgi (pid=4604): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/uno/dos/dos/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.172721 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432] mod_wsgi (pid=4604): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/uno/dos/dos/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "C:/uno/dos/dos/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     application = get_wsgi_application()\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "c:\\users\\blanca\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.177727 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "c:\\users\\blanca\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 24, in setup\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "c:\\users\\blanca\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\registry.py", line 89, in populate\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "c:\\users\\blanca\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\config.py", line 90, in create\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     module = import_module(entry)\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "c:\\users\\blanca\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
[Fri Jul 06 16:26:18.178732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 4604:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:50432] ImportError: No module named 'tres'\r
```

Comment: The error message quite clearly states `ImportError: No module named 'tres'`, so you simply have an import which it cannot find.

Comment: Thank you  for answer, but where do I have to include? my project work fine in the visrtualenv using runserver, I do not undestand where do I have to include.Thank you !

Comment: That depends. Somewhere in your code you have `import tres` or `from tres import...` and tres is either: a) an installed package (in which case running `pip list` from your virtualenv will show it) or b) a local module you created which didn't get carried over to the server or c) a typo, which maybe doesn't take effect locally because you're running different settings?

Comment: What version of python are you using and which mod_wsgi are you using? if using python 3.x.x you should install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` if you install `libapache2-mod-wsgi` while using python 3.x.x, you will get the "No Module named" error, the same if you are usin python python 2.7.x and install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`